# Netbeans IDE unusable under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having problems with the Netbeans IDE under a Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install. Starting the main window of Netbeans works, but klicking the button for "New Project" results in nothing happening. No window for further settings appears.

Command "java -version":

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

To install Netbeans, I downloaded it from [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/).

Is this a known error? Is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT:**

The Netbeans version I installed was 8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans v8.x doesn't run with Java 9, but with Java 8 (or lower) only.
(This is because Oracle unfortunately broke compatibility between Java 8 and Java 9.)
Netbeans 9 does run with Java 9, but Netbeans 9 is still alpha/beta status, not full version yet.

So you could either:

- a) use Java 8 to run your Netbeans 8.x
- b) use Netbeans 9 alpha/beta to run with your Java 9.

Ad a) From Oracle you could download a Java 8 for Linux, untar it and use it for Netbeans 8.

Ad b) On the Netbeans' download page you could on the top right switch to "Development" and then download a nightly build which normally is Netbeans 9 alpha/beta. But please be aware about the alpha/beta status, i.e. bugs.

Comment: Aw, strange that Oracle does such things, having errors between versions. Anyway, I heard that Oracle is giving away Netbeans to the Apache foundation.

Comment: Yes, the Open-Source project Netbeans is being transfered to the Apache foundation. Please see news on Apache's incubating web-site: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65873923